# What is the meaning of "in season as well as out"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "in season as well as out" ?

Full sentence:

> It is more likely to stay that way if we continued to do what's right — **in season as well as out**.

Comment: Can you give more context? Maybe the paragraph?

Comment: the article
http://feedmetothefish.blogspot.com/2009/10/lee-wei-lings-half-glass-in-washington.html

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the usage of the phrase [**as well as**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+well+as), meaning *and in addition*:

> *conj.*
>   And in addition: *courageous as well as strong.*

In your example:

> It is more likely to stay that way if we continued to do what's right — in season **and in addition** *out of season*.

You could use *and also* in place of *and in addition*.